# One-liner for conditional Cartesian Product of list of strings with list of tuples in python

Tags: python, string, tuples, python-itertools

I have a list of strings and a list of tuples.

**Input:**

```
string_list = ['www.cars.com/BMW/' ,'www.cars.com/VW/']
tuple_list = [('BMW','green'), ('BMW','blue'), 
               ('VW','black'), ('VW','red'), ('VW','yellow')]
```

*First step*: For every key in `string_list`, I need to filter for matching key/value pair in `tuple_list`:

```
string_list = ['www.cars.com/BMW/']
tuple_list = [('BMW','green'), ('BMW','blue')]
```

*Second step*: In one final output list, I need to form the Cartesian product of all strings in `string_list` with every matching key/value pair in `tuple_list`:

**Output:**

```
results_list = ['www.cars.com/BMW/green','www.cars.com/BMW/blue', 
  'www.cars.com/VW/black''www.cars.com/VW/red','www.cars.com/VW/yellow']
```

My current approach uses a series of nested `for`-loops, which comes at the cost of being slow, ugly and too long.

**How to efficiently form a conditional Cartesian Product between a list of strings and a list of tuples in python?**

Comment: Is it VM or VW?

Comment: VW, edited (sorry)

Comment: Do you actually need this as a list, or just anything you can iterate over? Because `itertools.product` or a nested genexpr will probably be faster than a nested listcomp if you don't need a list, but a listcomp will probably be faster than passing either of those to the `list` constructor.

Comment: any iterable is fine, the list is not really required

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One liner:

```
result = [s + b for s in string_list for a, b in tuple_list if a in s]
```

Basically, still two for loops.

```
>>> print(result)
['www.cars.com/BMW/green', 'www.cars.com/BMW/blue', 'www.cars.com/VW/black', 'www.cars.com/VW/red', 'www.cars.com/VW/yellow']
```

Comment: works like a charm, is ~10 times faster and only 1 SLOC - perfect

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

```
string_list = ['www.cars.com/BMW/' ,'www.cars.com/VW/']
tuple_list = [('BMW','green'), ('BMW','blue'),
               ('VW','black'), ('VW','red'), ('VW','yellow')]


print([color+i[1] for i in tuple_list for color in string_list if i[0] in color])
```

output:

```
['www.cars.com/BMW/green', 'www.cars.com/BMW/blue', 'www.cars.com/VW/black', 'www.cars.com/VW/red', 'www.cars.com/VW/yellow']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you pre-build a dictionary for lookups, you can improve performance a bit more:

**Given**

```
import collections as ct


colors =  ct.defaultdict(list)
for k, v in tuple_list:
    colors[k].append(v)

colors
# defaultdict(list, {'BMW': ['green', 'blue'], 'VW': ['black', 'red', 'yellow']})
```

**Code**

```
[s + c for s in string_list for c in colors[s[13:-1]]]
```

Output

```
['www.cars.com/BMW/green',
 'www.cars.com/BMW/blue',
 'www.cars.com/VW/black',
 'www.cars.com/VW/red',
 'www.cars.com/VW/yellow']
```

**Performance**

```
%timeit -n 100000 [s + b for s in string_list for a, b in tuple_list if a in s]  # @iBug
%timeit -n 100000 [s + c for s in string_list for c in colors[s[13:-1]]]         # proposed    
# 100000 loops, best of 3: 3.54 µs per loop
# 100000 loops, best of 3: 2.83 µs per loop
```